# Algorithm for determining if one string could be changed into another by insertion of characters?

Tags: algorithm, insertion

Let's say I have a "target string" (or list, doesn't really matter) of some length N.  For simplicity's sake, let's say there are two and only two possible characters, "A" and "B".  So, for example, maybe the target string is "ABBABB".

I am then given a test string of some length <= N (again, the same two possible characters).  I want to determine whether or not the test string can be transformed into the target string under the constraint that the only legal transformation is the insertion of characters.

For example, let's again say the target is ABBABB, and the test is BBB.  Then the answer is yes, the test can be transformed into the target; for example: BBB -> BBAB -> ABBAB -> ABBABB.

But if the test were BABA, then it could not be transformed into the target, since the target begins with an A, the test does not, and inserting an A into the test won't work because that would cause it to have more A's than the target has.

Obviously, I could make this yes-or-no determination by brute force, plowing through all possible sequences of character insertions.  But is there a more efficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first glance, the simple answer seems to be if the test string is sequentially contained in the target string then your test passes.

Something like:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (char c in target) {
    if (i == test.Length) return true; // Found all test chars
    if (test[i] == c) {
        i++; // found this test char; check for next
        if (i == test.Length) break;
    }
}
return i == test.Length; // Found all test chars
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming to work this out. Let X be the initial string and Y be the final string. Let us work the opposite problem, i.e. deleting from Y and see if we can get X.

```
F(Y,X) = (if X[0]=Y[0]: F(X[1:],Y[1:] ) or F(Y[1:],X)
```

End condition: `If X='', return True elsif Y='' return False`

Note that, as in all dynamic programming problems, you need to calculate and store F(X[i:],F[j:]) for len(X)*len(Y) different combinations of (i,j).

Answer (score 0):

1) Transform the test/target strings to arrays, in which each element is a pair that describes the number of the connected "A"s and "B"s.

e.g. ABBABB ==> { (1,2) (1,2) }; BBB ==> { (0,3) }; BABA ==> { (0,1) (1,1) (1,0) }

2) Define element level contain: P1 (a,b) contains P2 (c,d) if a>=c and b>=d

Define two operations on two elements P1 (a,b) and P2 (c,d)

mergeA(P1,P2) ==> (a+c,d);

mergeB(P1,P2) ==> (a,b+d)

3) Now we have an abstracted problem: given the test array {T1, T2, ..., Tn} and the target array {A1, A2, ... Am}, indicate if the target array contains the test array. Here "contain" can be defined recursively.

Target array contains test array if
i. Target array has the same or more elements than the test array;
ii. either for each i in [1,m] Ai contains Ti

or

mergeA(A1,A2), A3, A4 ... contains the test array

or

mergeB(A1,A2), A3, A4 ... contains the test array

4) Pseudo code

```
bool ifContain(Pair[] target, Pair[] test) {
    if (test.length>target.length) return false;
    if (test.length()==1) 
        return (target.A>=test.A && target.B>=test.B);
    return   (ifContain(target[0], test[0]) && ifContain(targe(1,:),test(1,:)))
        || ifContain(Pair(target[0].a,target[0].b+target[1].b)+target(2,:),test)
        || ifContain(Pair(target[0].a+target[1].a+target[1].b)+target(2,:),test);
}
```